# html one image displays one won't

Tags: html

While working on a page I'm trying to change some images. The original loads fine, but when I change it it won't show, checked the path and it seems right and made sure the file name is spelled right. Not sure what it could be.

```
<img src="..img/DSC00030.JPG"style="width:100%; height: 450px;">
```

UPDATE: On the off chance that it would help I deleted all the images I was using and redownloaded them, this time putting all in the same folder. When I use this image it shows up fine

```
<img src="../img/portfolio/images/DSC00028.JPG" style="width:100%; height: 450px;">
```

But this one doesn't show at all. Both are in the same folder.

If it helps at all these are images I am trying to use in a img carousel.

Comment: share a code snippet please

Comment: Clear your cache and check your dev tools for messages

Comment: You're missing a space  between the ending quotes of the src and the style keyword **DSC00030.JPG"style** It should be: `<img src="..img/DSC00030.JPG" style="width:100%; height: 450px;">`

Comment: Thank you for that tip Fluffy, but no luck in fixing the problem

Comment: I've just seen your update - make sure that the image name matches *exactly* the filename, including the case. I've answered this question at least twice where the extension was uppercase for some files and lowercase for others, e.g. `DSC00030.jpg` instead of `DSC00030.JPG` :)